# setting signal handler with std::signal - are there 'conditions' for failure?

Tags: c++, signals, posix, c++17

Looking at the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal)

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal

Under return value it is stated:

> Previous signal handler on success or SIG_ERR on failure (setting a
>   signal handler can be disabled on some implementations).

Im trying to understand, if/how this situation is best handled. Does this for example indicate that on platforms that support it - it never returns the failure code ? (and success can then be assumed)

Answer (score 0):

> Does this for example indicate that on platforms that support it - it never returns the failure code?

No.

It could fail if, for example, you pass invalid signal numbers e.g.,

```
std::signal(999, signal_handler); /* 999 isn't a valid signal number */
```

It could also fail if you try to set a handler for `SIGKILL` or `SIGSTOP` because they can't caught or ignored.

> setting a signal handler can be disabled on some implementations.

This is just an additional information in case if you're correctly calling `std::signal` and yet it could return `SIG_ERR`. It doesn't indicate that `std::signal` could not fail for any other reason.

In practice, you always need to check the return value so that you can be sure that the signal handler is actually set/active as you intended and if it fails,  handle accordingly.

```
if ( std::signal(SIGINT, signal_handler) == SIG_ERR ) {
    std::cerr << "Couldn't set a signal handler for SIGINT\n";
    ...
}
```